# C# Azure Storage Queue - Can write, can't read, and weird things

Tags: c#, azure, queue, storage

I'm pretty new to Azure Queue Storage. I'm just trying to do a basic thing: writing a message and reading a message.

Firstly, I have a weird problem. Googling around, both Microsoft and users say that the CloudQueue class has sync and async methods. But my Intellisense shows me only async methods. For example, if I try to use the GetMessage method, VS says it doesn't exist and I must use GetMessageAsync. Why?

Anyway...

For the configuration part, everything seems to work, because I can write messages into the Queue without any problem.

```
public async Task Write(string message)
    {
        await AzureQueue.AddMessageAsync(new CloudQueueMessage(message), TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2), TimeSpan.Zero, null, null);
    }
```

Instead, I've problem with reading. The code I'm using is simply this:

```
    public async Task StartReading()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            var message = await AzureQueue.GetMessageAsync();
            if (message != null)
            {
                await AzureQueue.DeleteMessageAsync(message);
            }
        }
    }
```

AzureQueue is just the CloudQueue object I'm using for writing (with success) and I'd like to use for reading (but it doesn't work).

Can anyone more expert of this topic help me please?

API Web ASP.NET Core project with NET Core 5.0.0

Package WindowsAzure.Storage 9.3.3

Comment: Please edit your question and include the SDK and its version you're using. There are many Storage SDKs available with different methods.

Comment: That is a rather old package. Try [the new one](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Storage.Queues//). The [README](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/master/sdk/storage/Azure.Storage.Queues/README.md) should get you going.

Comment: Uhm... I didn't notice that 9.3.3 was deprecated!!! SORRY!